# Python : Extending Exception class

Tags: python, exception

What I am trying to do is to extend the base `ImportError` Exception, so whenever it is called, it does somethings else as well

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="logs", level=logging.DEBUG)

class ImportError(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message

        logging.warning(self.message)



import module
```

But this doesn't work, can some one please tell me how can we achieve something like this..

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ImportError` is a built-in exception; an import failure will not look for the exception in the current module globals.

In fact, in Python 2, the import machinery doesn't even look in builtins for this; it uses the *C equivalent* of the exception, [`PyExc_ImportError`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html#standard-exceptions). You cannot replace the exception with your own.

Just catch the exception at the top level of your python main script:

```
try:
    main()  # or whatever function is your main entrypoint
except ImportError:
    logging.exception('Import oopsie')
```

or raise a custom exception in a exception handler instead. This is *far* clearer to future maintainers of your code than hacking additional features into standard exceptions.

In Python 3.1 and up, the import machinery has been largely reimplemented using a lot more Python code, and there you *can* do this by using the [`builtins` module](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/builtins.html) and assigning to `builtins.ImportError`, but I'd **strongly** advice against such hackery. If you *do* go this route, note that `ImportError` is passed `name` and `path` keyword arguments in addition to `message`.

Comment: ohk, so it means that i can not do what i am trying to do, instead i can create my custom `Exception` class and raise that when i get a `ImportError` ??

Comment: @abhishekgarg: Exactly.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, also i have many `try except` in my script, can i also do a `try except` for the whole main function like you've shown in your example instead of several different ones??

Comment: @abhishekgarg: That depends on what should happen when you have an import error; do you want to continue right after the failed `import` statement or do you want to end your program?

Comment: i want to end the program whenever i get any exception either ImportError, IOError, or any other exception. i would like to do something like 

`try:
    main()
except Exception, e:
    logging.error(e)`

Comment: Use `logging.exception()`; it's the same as `logging.error()` but captures the exception *and* the traceback, much more useful. :-) If you want to end the program, use *one* exception handler at the top.

Comment: @abhishekgarg: you are probably interested in [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). You could use it to log unhandled exceptions. btw, it is not stressed enough that overriding `builtins.ImportError` is a *bad idea*.